# SQL Nested Query, AVERAGE

Tags: sql, postgresql, nested, average

i'm new in SQL.
i have 3 tabels of: doctor, patient, and visit.
such that every 'visit' connect between a patient that come to some doctor.
the fields are:

Doctor (did, dname, specialty, clinic)

Patient (pid, pname, bmi, gender)

Visit (did, pid, vdate, fee)

i need to find the id of the doctor/doctors that the average bmi of his patients is the biggest.  and need that the average calculation takes into account
Each patient's doctor once, even if the patient visits the doctor several times.

i wrote this query:

```
SELECT V.did
FROM Visit V NATURAL JOIN Patient P
GROUP BY V.did 
HAVING AVG(P.bmi) >= ALL 
            (SELECT AVG(P.bmi)
            FROM Patient P NATURAL JOIN Visit V
            GROUP BY V.did)
ORDER BY did ASC
```

my problem is that for every doctor i need to take into account in the average calculation each patient of the doctor just once, even if the patient visits the doctor several times, and in my query i calculate a patient as described again and again in the number of times that he visit in the same doctor.
how can i change my query to fit the demand?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Forget about the NATURAL JOIN construction. Don't be lazy, specify the join conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `NATURAL JOIN`!  List the `JOIN` keys!  This is just good advice to prevent problems in the future.

If you want only one doctor -- even in the event of ties -- then aggregation, `ORDER BY`, and some version of `LIMIT` does what you want.

In standard SQL, this looks like:

```
SELECT V.did
FROM Visit V JOIN
     Patient P
     USING (pid)
GROUP BY V.did 
ORDER BY AVG(P.bmi) DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

The biggest issue with `NATURAL JOIN` is that it does not use properly declared `FOREIGN KEY` relationships.  Instead, it just relies on columns having the same name.  A second big problem is that the keys are hidden in the query.  So, the `JOIN` may not be doing what you expect -- and you might get no rows or a Cartesian product -- and it is very hard to debug.

Comment: Also, if a column later is added to one of the tables, having the same name as a column in the other table - the join condition will suddenly include these columns as well.

Answer (score 0):

> find the id of the doctor/doctors that the average bmi of his patients is the biggest

Your base query will look like this (Gordon Linoff commented already that `natural joins` should generally be avoided):

```
select d.did, d.dname, avg(p.bmi) avg_pmi
from doctor d
inner join visit on v.did = d.did
inner join patient p on p.pid = v.pid
group by d.did, d.dname
order by avg_pmi desc
```

Then you need to filter on the top doctor with ties. The actual solution depends on your RDMBS.

In Oracle:

```
select d.did, d.dname, avg(p.bmi) avg_pmi
from doctor d
inner join visit on v.did = d.did
inner join patient p on p.pid = v.pid
group by d.did, d.dname
order by avg_pmi desc 
fetch first 1 row with ties
```

In SQL Server:

```
select top (1) with ties d.did, d.dname, avg(p.bmi) avg_pmi
from doctor d
inner join visit on v.did = d.did
inner join patient p on p.pid = v.pid
group by d.did, d.dname
order by avg_pmi desc
```

In other systems, such as MySQL or Postgres, that do not support `with ties`, you can usually use window functions:

```
select did, dname, avg_pmi
from (
    select t.*, rank() over(order by avg_pmi desc) rn
    from (
        select d.did, d.dname, avg(p.bmi) avg_pmi
        from doctor d
        inner join visit on v.did = d.did
        inner join patient p on p.pid = v.pid
        group by d.did, d.dname
    ) t
) t
where rn = 1
```